# Creating Conda environment in windows 10 (but cannot reference to local directory)

Tags: python, anaconda

there are some strange problems regarding to conda (anaconda) on my local machine (windows 10).
After installed, I tried to create an environment like

```
conda create -n test
```

then the environment  is successfully created. Furthermore, the environment can reference to my local directory also, sth like C:\users\user_a\conda\conda\env\test. Verify using sys.path also

but then when I create another environment using similar command:

```
conda create -n test2
```

the environment test2 can only reference to the global package. Using sys.path showing it can only lookup global package directory also.

I tried to uninstall the whole OS / anaconda but no avail... What's the problem here?

*Edit I have edit with the correct syntax. And I have already activated my environment to check sys.path

*Edit 2
Here is the sys.path for respective environments:
{
`['', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3\\envs\\test\\python36.zip', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3\\envs\\test\\DLLs', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3\\envs\\test\\lib', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3\\envs\\test', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3\\envs\\test\\lib\\site-packages', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3\\envs\\test\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\test_user\\.ipython']`
and

```
'', 'D:\\Documents\\dev\\python\\my_projects\\my_proj', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'D:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\test_user\\.ipython'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the exact command you use to create the environments. The command that you are showing does not create an environment.

Comment: hi @darthbith, i have updated my commands.

Comment: Most likely the problem is that you haven't installed any packages in your new environment. You need to install some packages to use that environment.

Comment: @darthbith yes, i also had this speculation too, then I tried to install some package by `conda install` after `activate` my environment. but still my sys.path is note reflecting.
the strange thing is my **first** environment is always fine....

Comment: Then please show the output of `print(sys.path)` for both environments

Comment: @darthbith I have printed my sys.path for test and test2 respectively. thx.

Answer (score 1):

To create an environment you use `conda create`:

```
 c:\> conda create -n test
 c:\> conda create -n test2
```

Activate the environments using activate:

```
c:\> activate test
c:\> python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable, sys.path)"
c:\> deactivate
c:\> activate test2
c:\> python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable, sys.path)"
c:\> deactivate
```